# react native drawer get the navigation props

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, drawer

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <SomeStaticComp navigation={/* put here navigation props */}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Main} />
          </NavigationContainer>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

I have a question based on this documentation :

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/

In this code my Main components receive a navigation props where i can call function `navigation.openDrawer();` can i take this props and put him inside the SomeStaticComp ? i don't want to put this componants inside the Drawer.Screen ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can pass this props like this as per the documentation
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());

Comment: no you didn't undestand i want to pass the navigation props to the static comp :       <SomeStaticComp navigation={naviagation}/> but where can i take the naviagation element ?